# Declare a arbitrary data type

Tags: r, r-s4

Is it possible to declare a variable btw. representation like "obj" of a arbitrary type, that means an ancestor, where all data types derived from? So that I can appropriate each type to representation type? Should I put this flexible parameter into a list?

```
setClass(Class = "MyClass",
         representation = representation(obj = "object"
                                         )
         )


new("MyClassA",name="abc",typ=123)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by setting the class of a slot to be `ANY`. For instance:

```
setClass('foo', slots = c(obj = 'ANY'))
```

Then the slot `obj` in the class `foo` can be used to store an object of any class.

Finally, the `representation` parameter to `setClass` was recently deprecated with version 3.0.0 of R, and you should use the `slots` parameter (as above) instead.